# Bootstrap Issue. How to show these columns side by side on small devices?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

```css
 

.r1{
    border:1px solid black;
  
}

.r2{
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    
}

.r3{
    border:3px solid blue;
    text-align:center;
    
}

.t1{
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:red;
        text-align:center;
        border:1px solid black;
}

 
.head{
 
    border:2px solid black;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
}


 
 .c{
     height: 100px;
     border: 1px solid black
 }

.cell{
 
  border: 5px solid green;
 
}

.r4{
 
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylo2.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Russo+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   
   
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row r1">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row head">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                        Content
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row head">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                        Content
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row r1">
                <div class="col-md-12 c">
                Table1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row r2">
                <div class="col-md-6 c">
                Table2
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 c">
                Table3
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row r3">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 t1">
                                Heading
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row r">
                                <div class="col-md-1 cell">
                                1
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5 cell">
                                ABC
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5 cell">
                                234
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1 cell">
                                5
                                </div>
                                </div>
                             
                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row r3">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 t1">
                                    Heading
                                </div>
                                
                                </div>
                                <div class="row playerrow">
                                <div class="col-md-1 cell">
                                1
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5 cell">
                                ABC
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5 cell">
                                234
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1 cell">
                                5
                                </div>
                                </div>
                             
                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Hey,
when I'm on a Desktop Screen, the code is fine, but when I switch to my mobile Device, i would like to have the content of my last row  with the cells "1    ABC    234    5" besides each other too (like in desktop version) instead of each col building a new row. Also they shoud have a fixed with that not depends on its content.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. Remove the -md- from the classes and leave col-1, col-5 etc. Then they won't be responsive.